# COVID-19 vs HIV

Tags: covid-19, hiv

The way countries and people fighting COVID-19 these days is by quarantine so no one get infected and stop spreading the virus.

This method slow down the spread of the virus

We know that COVID-19 is easily transmitted virus, it can be transmitted by beath, touch, etc.

in the other hand HIV is more serious and have been for more 40 years and can be trasmitted sexually or blood transfusion..

HIV can be controlled easier.

Why HIV wasn't stopped using the quarantine method to stop it from the begining ?

and why not trying to contaminate the virus now and stop it by using same methods used for COVID-19?

Comment: Are you asking why HIV patients weren't isolated until they died?

Comment: As you pointed out, the virus responsible for COVID-19 is transmitted in a very different way to HIV as you pointed out. What benefit would there be in quarantine for HIV patients when it isn't transmitted through coughs, sneezes and touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who's been infected by COVID-19 is asymptomatic but can spread the disease for [no more than 14 days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019#Signs_and_symptoms).  Quarantine measures were started in China less than two months after the first case.

Someone who's been infected with HIV can be asymptomatic but capable of spreading the disease for [20 years or more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV/AIDS#Clinical_latency).  Further, the outbreak started sometime between [1910 and 1959](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV/AIDS#Origins), but wasn't identified as a disease until 1981.

Given the long asymptomatic period of HIV and the even longer delay in identifying it as a disease, it's pretty much impossible to stop it by quarantine.